# Python UDF for PIG Giving error

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-pig, user-defined-functions, udf

I have a Python UDF which converts the data from Hex to string. When I try to call the UDF on multiple fields, I am getting an error. Here is my Python UDF. Script is hex_to_str.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

@outputSchema("field:chararray")
def hextoStr(field):
if(field!=""):
        return field.decode("hex")
```

I am calling my pig script in below manner.

```
register file:/home/myuser/myfolder/hex_to_str.py using jython as convert;
data = LOAD '/user/abc/hexfile' using PigStorage(',') as (Name:chararray, age:chararray);
hex = foreach data generate convert.hextoStr(Name),convert.hextoStr(age);
dump hex;
```

This is the error I am getting while running the script.

```
INFO  org.apache.pig.scripting.jython.JythonFunction - Schema 'field:chararray' defined for func hextoStr
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1108:
 <line 2, column 19> Duplicate schema alias: field
```

The Error at the log file also did not say much.

```
<line 2, column 19> Duplicate schema alias: field
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.visitor.SchemaAliasVisitor.validate(SchemaAliasVisitor.java:75)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.visitor.SchemaAliasVisitor.visit(SchemaAliasVisitor.java:105)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOGenerate.accept(LOGenerate.java:246)
```

BUT, If I run the same script on only one field, then it works.

```
register file:/home/myuser/myfolder/hex_to_str.py using jython as convert;
data = LOAD '/user/abc/hexfile' using PigStorage(',') as (Name:chararray, age:chararray);
hex = foreach data generate Name,convert.hextoStr(age);
dump hex;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because the `@outputSchema("field:chararray")` decorator specifies the name (*alias*) and datatype (by default) of the *UDF*. When you call it twice, you're using the same alias twice in the `GENERATE`, and so the `Duplicate schema alias: field` error results.

You could run two separate `GENERATE`s, but I suspect you'll be able to use the function twice if you **re-alias**.

e.g something along these lines:

`hex = foreach data generate convert.hextoStr(Name) as field1,convert.hextoStr(age) as field2;`

Then each result will have its own alias, and that error should go away. Without re-aliasing, there wouldn't be a way for *Pig* to differentiate which result you were referring to elsewhere in the `GENERATE` statement.

**Reponse to comment from OP:**

I suspect you could replace `field` in the decorator with whatever specific string you'd like, but you would still have the issue of calling it twice on two different fields using the same alias, so you would still need to re-alias. I don't think it is possible to use a variable within the decorator, but re-aliasing back in your *Pig* script allows for full dynamic-ness. e.g. you could alias them as `age` and `name` or similar to match the actual field names.

More details on [Python UDFs](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/udf.html#python-udfs), which says, in part:

> Sample Schema String - `y:{t:(word:chararray,num:long)}`, variable names
>   inside a schema string are not used anywhere, they just make the
>   syntax identifiable to the parser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way I can use the actual fieldName into the UDF at @outputSchema("field:chararray"). For example in my case, is there any way I can refer the actual field name(Name or Age)instead of field

Comment: Sure, no problem. Re-aliasing in Pig basically accomplishes what you're asking for, I think (from an end-result perspective). See the edit in my answer above for more detail. Is there a specific reason you don't want to re-alias within the Pig script?

Comment: There is no specific reason but  I have a schema which contains more than 3000+ fields, I use a helper script to genrate the schema dynamically for this. In this case, it becomes little difficult for me to  generate the aliases. If I can handle that in the python UDF, then it becomes simple. Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure, no problem. With that many fields I can understand you wanting the UDF to be able to do that. Unfortunately, I don't think that's currently supported.